# UnityWebRequest constructor block in a ReadToEndAsync callback

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asynchronous, networking, io

I don't understand why the UnityWebRequest constructor doesn't return in this callback. Is it a thread problem ?

```
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("C:\\file.txt");

streamReader.ReadToEndAsync().ContinueWith((task) => {
    Debug.Log("read done");

    UnityWebRequest request = new UnityWebRequest();

    Debug.Log("web request created");
});
```

In the Unity console, I only see the "read done" message.

Comment: `ContinueWith` is probably executed on a background thread where the constructor of `UnityWebRequest` throws an exception you don't see in the main thread => the background task silently fails

Comment: yes it was definitely a thread problem but i found a solution that uses the main thread thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

someone finally gave me that solution:

```
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("C:\\file.txt");

async void AsyncRead(StreamReader reader) {
    Debug.Log("in the function");

    Task<String> task = reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    await task;

    Debug.Log("reading done");

    UnityWebRequest unityWebRequest = new UnityWebRequest();

    Debug.Log("web request created");
}

AsyncRead(streamReader);

Debug.Log("async reading started");
```

the UnityWebRequest constructor no longer blocks and i get what i want in the unity console:

```
in the function
async reading started

...more later...

reading done
web request created
```